# HTML Footer is overlaping inside the center content

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am designing a homepage template.  When I finished with my center content I started making the footer.  I quickly realized my footer is not at the bottom of the page but instead inside the center content and cannot figure out why.

***HTML:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file://C:/Workspace/MyWeblogicWorkspace/Purify/WebContent/CSS/index.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="navigationBar">
            <ul id="navigationBarList">
                <li><a id="test" href="http://www.google.com">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end of navigationBar -->
    </div><!-- end of header -->
    <div id="center">
        <p id="title">*******************</p>
        <p id="slogan">*******************</p>

        <div id="centerContent">
            <div id="contentOneBox">
                <p id="contentOneTitle">*******************</p>
                <p id="contentOneText">*******************!</p>
            </div><!-- end of contentOneBox -->
            <div id="contentTwoBox">
                <p id="contentTwoTitle">*******************</p>
                <p id="contentTwoText">**************************************.</p>
            </div><!-- end of contentTwoBox -->
            <div id="contentThreeBox">
                <p id="contentThreeTitle">*******************</p>
                <p id="contentThreeText">**************************************.</p>
            </div><!-- end of contentThreeBox -->
            <div id="contentFourBox">
                <p id="contentFourTitle">*******************</p>
                <p id="contentFourText">**************************************.</p>
            </div><!-- end of contentFourBox -->
        </div><!-- end of centerContent -->
    </div><!-- end of center -->
    <div id="footer">
        <p id="contact">*******************</p>
        <p id="copyright">*******************</p>
    </div><!-- end of footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

***CSS:***

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #221F51;
}

#header {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    height: 48px;
    max-height: 44px;
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#navigationBar {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#navigationBar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#navigationBar ul li a {
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigationBar ul li a:hover {
    color: gray;
}

#center {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
}

#title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 48px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#slogan {
    display: block;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#centerContent {
    display: block;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 990px;
}

#contentOneBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
}

#contentOneTitle {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 2px;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#contentOneText {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    height: 97px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#contentTwoBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
}

#contentTwoTitle {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 2px;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#contentTwoText {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    height: 97px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#contentThreeBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
}

#contentThreeTitle {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 2px;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#contentThreeText {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    height: 97px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#contentFourBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
}

#contentFourTitle {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 2px;    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#contentFourText {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    display: block;
    height: 97px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#contact {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#copyright {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here's fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/c74dy9dj/

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `clear: both;` to footer CSS:

```
#footer {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  border: 1px gray dotted;
  background-color: rgba(120,120,120,.5);
  clear: both; /* <-- check this out! */
}
```

Comment: thank you! I am guessing the clear tag overrides the effects of the floats?

Comment: Basically it makes element be pushed down under floated elements before it. In other words: *"The clear property specifies on which sides of an element floating elements are not allowed to float"*. In this case we use `both` value; you can also specify only one side: `left` or `right`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using floats which causes elements after a floating element to flow around it.

Here is a good explanation

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clear/

You can fix this by adding "clear: both" to #footer

```css
#footer {
    clear:both;
}
```